# How to parse contents of a file using sed/awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

My input file has its content in following format, where each column is separated by a "space"

```
string1<space>string2<space>string3<space>YYYY-mm-dd<space>hh:mm:ss.SSS<space>string4<space>10:1234567890<space>0e:Apple 1.2.3.4<space><space>string5<space>HEX
```

There are 2 "spaces" after "0e:Apple 1.2.3.4" because there is no 14th digit in this field/column. The entire "0e:Apple 1.2.3.4space" is treated as a single value of that column.

In the 7th column, **10:** represents the count of characters in the following string.

In the 8th column, **0e:** represents a hex value of 14. So, the HEX values mention the count of characters in the string that follows.

Like:

```
"0e:Apple 1.2.3.4 "--> this is the actual value in 8th column without " "  
    (I've mentioned " " to show that the 14th digit is empty)  

It's counted as  
0e:A p p l e   1 . 2 .   3  . 4    
   | | | | | | | | | |   |  | | |  
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1314
```

Let's consider first row from the input file as:

```
string1 string2 string3 yyyy-mm-dd 23:50:45.999 string4 10:1234567890 0e:Apple 1.2.3.4  string5 001e
```

where:

- `string1` is the value in 1st column
- `string2`  is the value in 2nd column
- `string3` is the value in 3rd column
- `yyyy-mm-dd` in 4th
- `23:50:50.999` in 5th
- `string3` in 6th
- `10:1234567890` in 7th  //there is no space at the end because it has 10 digits
- `0e:Apple 1.2.3.4` in 8th  //space at the end
- `string5` in 9th
- `001e` in 10th

Expected output:

```
string1,string2,string3,yyyy-mm dd,23:50:50.999,string3,1234567890,Apple_1.2.3.4,string5,30
```

Requirements:

1. Eliminate the counts from 7th and 8th column (`10:` & `0e:`)
2. The space b/w `Apple` and `1.2.3.4` should be replace by **"_"**
3. Hex value in the last column should be converted to decimal value.
4. Replace the "space" between columns with **","**
5. I've used hex value only in 10th column here. What if it's in several columns? Any way to convert it specific to certain columns?

I've tried using this:

```
$ cat input.txt |sed 's/[a-z0-9].*://g'
```

which gives output as:

```
string1,string2,string3,yyyy-mm-dd,45.999,string4,1234567890,Apple,1.2.3.4,,string5,001e
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean *preceding*?

Comment: So, basically, you have not tried to do anything yourself. The `sed` example you posted is obviously unsuitable for your requirements (except the first, possibly). And `sed` is not powerful enough for what you are trying to do. A `sed` guru would probably be able to write a two hundred line program to solve the problem, but it would be insanely difficult.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs my bad. It's following string. Edited it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MichaelVehrs yeah. My script just does the first. I'm able to do 4 with other script too. But not sure how to proceed with 2,3 and 5. Can we do it with awk? (Parsing string by string?)

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want on your example input:

```
awk -F "[ ]" '{sub(/.*:/, "", $7) sub(/.*:/, "", $8); printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s_%s,%s,%s,%d\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, "0x"$12}' input.txt
```

**Explanation of parts:**

`awk` [**`printf`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html#Control-Letters) allows you to specify an output format, so you can manually specify which fields you want to delimit with `,` and which you want to delimit with `_`.

[**`-F "[ ]"`**](https://docs.freebsd.org/info/gawk/gawk.info.Field_Separators.html) forces the field separator to be a single space so that it knows there is an empty field between two single spaces. The default behavior would be to allow multiple spaces to be a single delimiter, which is not what you want according to the question.

The [**`sub`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function allows you to do regular expression replacement, in this case removing the `..:` prefix in fields 7 and 8.

For field 12, we tell `printf` to output as a number ([**`%d`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html#Control-Letters)) and give as input the string in prefixed by [**`0x`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal_002dnumbers.html) so that it interprets it as hexadecimal.

*Note:* If it's not always the case that you want the output to be `$8_$9`, then you actually need to parse the hexadecimal prefix and count off characters in order to determine where the field ends. If that's the case, I would personally prefer to write the whole thing in something else, e.g. Python.